# Bootstrap containers expanding and contracting at every breakpoint passage

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have this page with a header, a content area and a footer as flex items. In order to keep the footer at the bottom of the screen, I gave the content area the class `flex-grow-1`.

Inside the content area, the structure is:
`container > row > col-md-8 / col-md-4`

My expectation is that the container wrapping everything else above would stick to the edges in small viewports and grow a margin as it gets bigger.

Small viewport:

```
|container|
```

Larger viewport:

```
|  container  |
```

and so on...

But what happens is that it keeps contracting and expanding as it crosses each breakpoint (sm|md|lg|xl). It's hard to describe, so you have to see it for yourself: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GVreOX).

- Resize the browser window to the left or right slowly and watch how
  all containers behave.

This is the weird effect I'm experiencing:

```
|container|          # small viewport
|  container  |
|    container    |
| container |          # medium viewport
|  container  |
|    container    |
| container |          # large viewport
|  container |
|    container    |
```

As you can see in the Codepen demonstration, this is also happening to all other containers in the page, such as the header and footer. I did not override anything from Bootstrap.

I need to understand why this happens, so I can fix it. This is a Symfony application using Webpack Encore to manage assets. Bootstrap is installed through Yarn and resides in node_modules on my project. This is the package: [bootstrap npm package v4.3.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap). I am importing Bootstrap's /dist/css/bootstrap.css and its JavaScript too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the `container` has different max-widths based on media query breakpoints...

From the bootstrap.css:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}
```

Therefore, the simplest way to achieve what you want is to use `.container-fluid` and set a `max-width` on it...

```
.container-fluid {
  max-width: 992px;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XvpLBp

Comment: Didn't see your edit. But yeah, that does what I want. Thank you!

Comment: It's intended behavior for Bootstrap's container. I don't know about Symfony.